# Android : Camera#takePicture() で写真を撮影すると、シャッター音が鳴らない

Tags: android

Android 向けにカメラアプリを開発しています。

`android.hardware.Camera#takePicture(Camera.ShutterCallback shutter, Camera.PictureCallback raw, Camera.PictureCallback jpeg)` を呼び出して撮影したデータをコールバックで取得するところは実装したところ、デフォルトのシャッター音が再生されることを期待したのですが、なぜかシャッター音が鳴りません。

デフォルトのシャッター音を再生するために必要な Camera パラメータなどが存在するのでしょうか？

補足：

- 念のため、 `takePicture` する前に、`Camera#enableShutterSound(true);` を呼び出して `true` が返ってきている事も確認しました。([enableShutterSound (boolean enabled) のAPI Doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#enableShutterSound(boolean)) を読む限り、これで正しくデフォルトのシャッター音が再生されるよう設定された筈)
- 標準(?)のカメラアプリ、 Instagram で撮影すると、2つのアプリで機種毎に同じサウンドが再生されています。（ので、それが各端末のデフォルトのシャッター音なのだろうと推測しています）
- `PictureCallback` 等で自前でサウンド再生する方法も考えられますが、二重になってしまうのは避けたいので気がすすみません。

環境 :

- Nexus 7 2014(4.4.4) ... 再生されない
- xperia Acro HD(4.0.4) ... 再生されない
- compileSdkVersion 21, buildToolsVersion '21.1.1'

Answer (score 2):

http://qiita.com/tao_s/items/13d809c12875a6a4b752 に書いてたのが効きました。

```
final Camera.ShutterCallback dummyCallback = new Camera.ShutterCallback() {
    @Override public void onShutter() {}
};
camera.takePicture(dummyCallback, null, this);
```

これだと音が鳴るけど、dummyCallbackがnullだと鳴らない。